# How to disable App Limits on macOS admin account, without passcode?

Tags: macos

I don't remember my passcode and those block-screens are getting annoying) There should be a way to disable it with admin privileges, but I cannot find any info on apple forums.

Edit: I DO remember my admin password. I don't have the 4 digit-passcode for Screen Time feature.

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/1495418/disable-screentime-on-mac-os-without-knowing-passcode-set-on-another-device?noredirect=1, https://appletoolbox.com/reset-the-screen-time-passcode-on-ios-12/

Answer (score 1):

If you've forgotten your admin password, then you can reset it using the steps shown in this [Apple document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860).

Comment: I remember my admin password. I don't remember passcode for App Limits.